# Old floor blending with new

Tags: floor, hardwood

We have two very different colors of floor, new vs old.  We liked the rich color of the old wood when we applied wood conditioner.  This same color can be achieved with red oak stain on the new, so old and new blend nicely.  A sample piece of each, both unvarnished, still look great and match after three days.

So to my project.... We stained the new wood red oak, like the sample, a day later I conditioned the old wood and got that rich color again.  So far so good. I then varnished the old wood, over the conditioner.  Everything was wonderful and colors were great!

A couple hours later, the old wood is fading in color, going back to it's dull self where as the sample still maintains the rich color with conditioner only.  What happened and how can I get the beautiful color that the conditioned wood has?  Was it acting like a wet floor and now it's drying?  Why is the sample keeping the color?

Thank you!

Comment: Was there an earlier treatment on the old floor that was not on the sample?

Comment: You need to remove a sample of the old wood from a corner of the room or where it will be under furniture, and experiment with that and a piece of new wood, with the full end to end process.  Try different products, different processes, keep trying til you like it.    Maybe putting the red stain on the old wood will help or maybe putting conditioner on the new wood?  Try it.   Alternately, don't go for a perfect match.  Find a nice contrast instead.

Comment: what is meant by "varnish"? An oil-based poly will keep the wet look. I thought conditioner is just meant to be used pre-stain, but maybe you have a different product...

Comment: Did you sand the old floor to the bare wood below? Wood flooring with different surface conditions absorbs and reflects the color after drying at different rates.